# Is "wherever it takes to.." ungrammatical

Tags: grammar

> wherever it takes to...

Is this proper grammar? I've heard,"Whatever it takes to do something", but this type is the first example for me.

> ...being a writer means going wherever it takes to find “the scale of things...

Comment: I can't find anything ungrammatical in that extract.

Comment: James below is right(correct).

Answer (score 4):

Note that the verb isn't necessarily "to go", and the pattern is the same as your "whatever" examples. `Wherever` replaces `Whatever` when the verb indicates movement.

> I will do **whatever** it takes to win the competition.
>
> I will eat **whatever** it takes to win the competition.

> I will walk **wherever** it takes to win the competition.
>
> I will fly **wherever** it takes to win the competition.

---

I think you might just be reading it wrongly:

Breaking it up into the following parts might make more sense:

```
      phrasal verb*      infinitive    
(going wherever it takes)(to find)
```

<sup>* I suppose this might just be two verbs, rather than a phrasal one, but they go together. My terminology might just be wrong. Feel free to edit.</sup>

Have a look at some other examples in different tenses

> He goes wherever it takes to find food
>
> The dog went wherever it took to seek shelter
>
> The missionary will go wherever it takes to spread the message.

Also, notice that although there are two verbs, only the first matches the number. `It` stays the same

Comment: But in this example, there's no object after takes...so what'S going on?

Comment: "the scale of things" is the object in that extract.

Comment: no no, if you mean what you wrote up there, there must be an object after take...like I let my dog go wherever it took me. like that. so what's going on?

Comment: Does the edit, showing the similarities with "whatever it takes" help?

Comment: Also, there are objects in each of my examples: `food`, `shelter`, `the message` are all the objects of their respective sentences

Answer (score 1):

There are no records for the string *wherever it takes to* in either the Corpus of Contemporary American English or the British National Corpus, and there are no citations that include it in the Oxford English Dictionary. The Corpus of Global Web-Based English has just these two records, the first from the Philippines, the second from Australia:

> He taught me to have courage to go wherever it takes to make it.
>
> From wherever it takes to undumb the nation.

It looks ungrammatical to me. *Whatever it takes* is grammatical, because it means whatever thing (effort, time, energy, money) it takes. You can take a thing, but you can’t, in the same sense, take a place. The difficulty can be resolved by writing ‘being a writer means going wherever necessary to find . . .’

TrevorD’s examples are grammatical because the construction is different. In all three, ‘it takes’ has an object (*him* in the first and third, *you* in the second). But  *wherever* is an adverb, and, as such, cannot be the object of *takes*. *Whatever*, by contrast, is a pronoun, and can.

Comment: Correct. The `it takes` in this context is the same as in `it takes a screwdriver and a hammer to assemble the furniture`. When I say that I'll bring `whatever it takes to assemble the furniture`, it implies I'll bring a screwdriver and a hammer. The same kind of substitution should be possible with `wherever`, but does not work for `wherever it takes`

Answer (score 0):

As @JamesWebster has illustrated, the basic phrase is:

> [going] wherever [it] takes

and, although it is often followed by an infinite verb (*to ...*), is not necessarily followed by *to*.

For example, the following are also examples of the same phrase:

> He needs to go wherever the job takes him.
>   You need to go wherever it takes you.
>   He followed the path wherever it took him.

So, yes, it is 'grammatical' and a common idiom.